# Would heavy usage of sessions in C# on an IIS server be a Memory or a FileStorage issue?

Tags: asp.net, cache

We have a site being setup on IIS 6 (or 7 if im really lucky) and was told not to use sessions too much as the server had limited application memory (32bit Server 2Gig of ram for IIS).
My understanding (based on unix/linux apache hosting and lighttpd) was that session data etc was stored in actual files.

Is it memory or filestorage?

Comment: I had a brain fart and am updating my answer......  Please reread!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there are a number ways to store session information (assuming you're using ASP.NET).  In memory is one option which you do need to be careful of.  I believe you can change it via your app's web.config.  You can use other things like cookies or SQL Server to store state info.  Here's a MSDN article that talks about [ASP.NET session state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).  [Here's another article](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/03/24/sessionstate.html) that discusses choosing the storage location.

Comment: Bugger, that seems a tad daft and memory hogging.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for the original post... Was in classic ASP mode in which session state was stored in memory.

Comment: Thanks again; I still have to deal with Classic ASP so its handy to know all of it :o)  Ta